# Xcode 4.2 - App Loader: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I have never had this problems until I began to use Xcode 4.2. I'm getting the following error trying to upload my app:

> Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found. Your minimum os
>   version is below 3.2, so you must define CFBundleIconFile or provide a
>   default Icon.png that is 57x57

I have an "Icon.png" image and is 57x57. I tried add it and remove it from info.plist. No success. I don't know what to do.

[image]

Here is my info.plist file

[image]

Info.plist edited again

[image]

**SOLUTION**

Thanks for your comments. The problem was that I was not following the right steps to prepare the app for submission in Xcode 4. It's very different to Xcode 3.2. If you follow the steps of [this guide](http://weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442) you will not have the issues I had.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To avoid more replies, I post the solution (solved myself)

> The problem was that I was not following the correct step to prepare
>   the app for submission in Xcode 4. It's very different to Xcode 3.2.
>   If you follow the steps of [link]weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442 this guide
>   you will not have the issues I had.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The answer below by RickJansen is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your Info.plist has these entries and that the file names match exactly (iOS 5 icons may not be necessary but it doesn't hurt to include them):

[image]

Here are the pages that Apple talks about the Icon guidelines:

[iOS HIG - Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)
[Apple Technical Q&A QA1686 - App Icons on iPad and iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html)

---

This is the same thing as above but with the "Raw" key/value pairs:

[image]

Comment: I did all you sugested and still getting the same error. I have updated the question with the screenshot of my info.plist and my project navigator files. Hope you can help me.

Comment: @T I dont see in your screenshot a line for just "Icon file" (w/o an `s`).  Double check because there are two very similar but different entries: "Icon file", and "Icon files" (one with an `s` and one without).  The plural one has the 6 sub items, but the singular is just a string name of the icon file.

Comment: @C Yes, I noticed that when I uploaded the screenshot. I fixed that but still I'm getting the error.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The problem was that I was not following the correct step to prepare the app for submission in Xcode 4. It's very different to Xcode 3.2. If you follow the steps of [link]http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2442 this guide you will not have the issues I had.

Answer (score 4):

The actual problem is that the specification of icon files in the Info.plist changed with iOS 5. Note that it says "Icon files (iOS 5)" in the Info.plist. If you specify a build target before 5.0 you will get the error messages mentioned, because specifying the icon files is different prior to 5.0! You can either change your build target to 5.0, or add icon specifications for older iOS. (That is actually what happened by adding the CFBundleIconFiles array to the Info.plist)

So, the problem is not in Xcode 3.2 versus Xcode 4.2, but in the iOS version you target with your App.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this issue with my app submission, I tried my best to assure icon is 57x57 pixel & properly added but somehow validations always failed. 
Finally I removed the app icons from Project summary, Plist file & project Navigator. Renamed these files in finder and added again to the project. Somehow this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem make sure that remove transparent pixel from icon i solved it

Answer (score 0):

Wanna share my experience (This is really a frustrating problem). I am using XCode 4.6.3

When I almost gave up after some long hours of trial-n-error, I did the followings:

1. Remove all icon files (the references) from my project.
2. Remove the "Icon Files" entry in the info.plist
3. Remove the App icons from the "Summary" tab of the project navigator (right-click on the icons and choose "Delete") for all the "Deployment" sections
4. Make sure the icon file names are the same as specified at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) ("I"con.png, instead of "i"con.png)
5. Clean the project.
6. Drag-and-drop the icon files into the "Resources"->"images" group in the project. And check the box for "Copy items to the destination group's folder(if needed).
7. Open the Project Navigator and make the App icons visible (which should be empty now)
8. Drag-and-drop the icon files (one-by-one) from the project file list to the App icon space (not from Finder). There will be a warning appear saying that a file is exist and confirm replacing it. Confirm.
9. After doing 8, you can check the "Info" tab (i.e. the info.plist) of project navigator. The "Icon Files" entry appeared.
10. Build the project (for Archive) again.

I don't know which step above did the trick (that's why I tried to be very specific about each step, though some looks silly), but it works for me. Good Luck!