# Xcode validation error: Unexpected value for key: CFBundleIconFile is not a string

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, validation, icons

I'm trying to validate an iOS application for first time.

I had a lot of obstacles until come this step, but I couldn't resolve by myself, so I decide write a question for this awesome comunity.

I got this error in the validation process of the app:

Image: http://oi43.tinypic.com/292qvk5.jpg

My .plist file name is: appxxx-Info.plist
The first question is: the error is reference a file named Info.plist, but I haven't this file!, again, my file is named appxxx-Info.plist

So, I checked the appxxx-Info.plist file to made sure that I had included all neccessary icons for the app. I did have them all.

Image http://oi40.tinypic.com/2a66lqx.jpg

I went to the Summary tab project's target in Xcode and I loaded the proper image for each "device" (iphone/ipod/ipad) and everything is fine! (I never seen a yellow warning triangle)

Anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to question #1: Xcode renames your info plist to “Info.plist” when it builds your app bundle. The organizer is validating the built app bundle, not your raw source.

In response to #2: CFBundleIconFile [should be a string, not an array](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102043).

Answer (score 0):

To help with your error I suggest you go through the following links :-

[CFBundleIconFile and CFBundleIconFiles in info.plist](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/52701-need-both-cfbundleiconfile-and-cfbundleiconfiles-in-info-plist.html)

[CFBundleIconFiles Key is not Showing Up in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241652/cfbundleiconfiles-key-is-not-showing-up-in-xcode)

[Core Foundation Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html)

Also to specify icons for your app please go through

[How do I specify both icons for a universal iPhone/iPad app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480563/how-do-i-specify-both-icons-for-a-universal-iphone-ipad-app) and [Xcode 4.2 - App Loader: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370940/xcode-4-2-app-loader-unable-to-verify-icon-dimensions-no-icon-found)